Django formset is valid but returns empty dict list
I'm attempting to render a form that is a table where each row contains a name and a checkbox to allow the user to select players for a game.  Googling around I've realized that I need to generate a formset so that each line in the table is a separate form.
I finally have the table rendering correctly and posting without errors but what I've found is that while the formset is valid, the cleaned data contains a list of empty dicts.  I found some StackOverflow posts that were similiar that said to create your own Formset class and set empty_permitted=True but that did not fix my issue.
I can't seem to get passed this issue so any help is appreciated.
Code Snippets
# forms.py
class InvitePlayerForm(forms.Form):
    """
    Form to invite players to the new game
    """
    invited = forms.CheckboxInput()



class InvitePlayerFormset(BaseFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.forms:
            form.empty_permitted = False

# views.py:

def create_game_players(request):
    """
    View to invite players to a game
    """
    context = dict()
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == "POST":
        num_players = request.session["invites"]["num_players"]
        print(f"num_players: {num_players}")
        invite_formset = formset_factory(InvitePlayerForm, formset=InvitePlayerFormset, extra=num_players)
        invite_forms = invite_formset(data=request.POST)

        print(f"Formset valid: {invite_forms.is_valid()}")
        print(f"request.POST: {request.POST}")
        print(f"changed_data: {invite_forms.has_changed}")

        data = invite_forms.cleaned_data
        print(f"Cleaned data: {data}")

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("game_list_view"))

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        player_list = list(CustomUser.objects.all())
        num_players = len(player_list)
        invite_formset = formset_factory(InvitePlayerForm, formset=InvitePlayerFormset, extra=num_players)
        # context["num_players"] = num_players
        context["first_names"] = [u.first_name for u in player_list]
        context["last_names"] = [u.last_name for u in player_list]
        context["invite_formset"] = invite_formset()
        request.session["invites"] = {"num_players": num_players}

    return render(request, "create_game_players.html", context)

# create_game_players.html template
<h4>Invite Players</h4>
          <div class="form-group">

            <form method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}

              {{ invite_formset.management_form.as_p }}

              <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Invited</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {% for invite_form in invite_formset.forms %}

                  <tr>
                    <td>{{first_names|get:forloop.counter0}} {{last_names|get:forloop.counter0}}</td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="invited_{{forloop.counter0}}" id="{{forloop.counter0}}"/>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block">Next</button>
            </form>

          </div>

Console Output
[05/Apr/2024 14:32:31] "POST /create_game/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[05/Apr/2024 14:32:31] "GET /create_game/players HTTP/1.1" 200 8961
num_players: 21
Formset valid: True
request.POST: <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['HzZu3tHpBIHDVSwPa4UJZTjWCNC52s7Njz2NRhTvJPXDzNKsSonFNRxyUNK1NtZu'], 'form-TOTAL_FORMS': ['21'], 'form-INITIAL_FORMS': ['0'], 'form-MIN_NUM_FORMS': ['0'], 'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': ['1000'], 'invited_0': ['on'], 'invited_1': ['on'], 'invited_2': ['on']}>
changed_data: <bound method BaseFormSet.has_changed of <InvitePlayerFormFormSet: bound=True valid=True total_forms=21>>
Cleaned data: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
[05/Apr/2024 14:32:39] "POST /create_game/players HTTP/1.1" 302 0


I think instead of accessing invite_forms.cleaned_data, you should loop through each form in the formset and check the value of the 'invited' field.
Try this view:
def create_game_players(request):
    """
    View to invite players to a game
    """
    context = dict()
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == "POST":
        num_players = request.session["invites"]["num_players"]
        print(f"num_players: {num_players}")
        invite_formset = formset_factory(InvitePlayerForm, formset=InvitePlayerFormset, extra=num_players)
        invite_forms = invite_formset(data=request.POST)

        print(f"Formset valid: {invite_forms.is_valid()}")
        print(f"request.POST: {request.POST}")
        print(f"changed_data: {invite_forms.has_changed}")

        if invite_forms.is_valid():
            selected_players = []
            for form in invite_forms:
                if form.cleaned_data.get('invited'):
                    selected_players.append(form.cleaned_data.get('invited'))

            print(f"Selected players: {selected_players}")

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("game_list_view"))

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        player_list = list(CustomUser.objects.all())
        num_players = len(player_list)
        invite_formset = formset_factory(InvitePlayerForm, formset=InvitePlayerFormset, extra=num_players)
        # context["num_players"] = num_players
        context["first_names"] = [u.first_name for u in player_list]
        context["last_names"] = [u.last_name for u in player_list]
        context["invite_formset"] = invite_formset()
        request.session["invites"] = {"num_players": num_players}

    return render(request, "create_game_players.html", context)

Also make sure that the 'invited' field in your form is correctly defined and mapped to the checkboxes in your template.
Edit:
Try to use BooleanField in forms, so:
class InvitePlayerForm(forms.Form):
    """
    Form to invite players to the new game
    """
    invited = forms.BooleanField(label='Invited', required=False)

Then, in your template, use the correct name attribute for the checkbox input:
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="invited_{{ forloop.counter0 }}" id="{{ forloop.counter0 }}"/>


Either way doesn't work.  The cleaned data is still an empty dict.  I'm not convinced the form.CheckboxInput is mapped correctly to the template.  I changed the name attribute in the template to be "invited" which matches the form class attribute name in the Form class.  The id attributes are unique integers for each of the check boxes.  Is this correct?  This is how I've mapped other form widgets to manual templates and they work.

with your latest change, the form is changed, bound and valid.  When I iterate on the formset and print out each form.cleaned_data dictionary it is no longer empty, however when I check boxes they still return as false.  So progress, but still not quite working.
`form cleaned data: {"invited": False}'
